# SwiftUI Drag gesture in vertical ScrollView that contains horizontal ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to implement a `Pager` that allows a user to move between two views by swiping left or right. Each of these views is a `ScrollView` that contains many elements (mostly `VStacks` and `HStacks` with `Text` elements, but there are also horizontal `ScrollView`s containing `Text` elements).

I attach a `highPriorityGesture(DragGesture())` to the Pager and as the user drags I offset the views so that one view becomes visible and the other slides off the screen. In the drag gesture's `.onEnded` callback if `translation.width` `predicatedTranslation.width` exceeds a threshold then I switch the view (so that the user doesn't have to swipe through the whole screen, but only half of it) and if it doesn't exceed the threshold I make the view snap back to its initial position.

The problem appears when one of the two views embedded in the `Pager` contains a horizontal `ScrollView`. Then the `highPriorityGesture(DragGesture())` misbehaves. What happens is the following:

- the horizontal `ScrollView` scrolls to the left/right
- the `highPriorityGesture(DragGesture())` picks up that drag and `.onChanged` callback fires and updates the offset, but the `.onEnded` callback never fires

The result is that the `Pager` moves one view a bit to the left/right, but since the `.onEnded` callback doesn't fire it just leave that view there instead of making it move back to the initial position (so it might end in showing 95% of the first view and 5% of the second view).

I also tried using `.gesture(DragGesture())` instead of `highPriorityGesture(DragGesture())`, but it still picks up the drag from the child `ScrollView`.

Is there any way of making the child horizontal `ScrollView` to exclusively handle the its drag?

EDIT:

It happens also if one of the two views is simply a vertical `ScrollView` without any nested horizontal `ScrollViews`. Somehow even though it is vertical it can be dragged diagonally.

```
struct Pager2View<T1: View, T2: View>: View {

let pageCount: Int
let pageOne: T1
let pageTwo: T2
@Binding var currentIndex: Int
@State private var translation: CGSize = .zero
@State private var offset: CGFloat = 0.0

func exceedsThreshold(gesture: DragGesture.Value, geometryWidth: CGFloat) -> Bool {
    (abs(gesture.translation.width) > (geometryWidth / 2)) || (abs(gesture.predictedEndTranslation.width) > (geometryWidth / 2))
}

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        HStack {
            self.pageOne.frame(width: geometry.size.width)
            self.pageTwo.frame(width: geometry.size.width)
        }
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, alignment: .leading)
        .offset(x: self.offset)
        .onChange(of: currentIndex) { value in
            withAnimation {
                if currentIndex == 0 {
                    self.translation.width = 0
                } else {
                    self.translation.width = -geometry.size.width
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: translation) { value in
            withAnimation {
                self.offset = max(-geometry.size.width, min(0, -geometry.size.width * CGFloat(currentIndex) + self.translation.width))
            }
        }
        .highPriorityGesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { gesture in
                    self.translation = gesture.translation              
                }
                .onEnded { gesture in
                    
                    if exceedsThreshold(gesture: gesture, geometryWidth: geometry.size.width) {
                        if gesture.translation.width < 0 && exceedsThreshold(gesture: gesture, geometryWidth: geometry.size.width) && currentIndex == 0 {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.translation.width = 0
                                currentIndex = min(self.pageCount - 1, currentIndex + 1)
                                
                            }
                        } else if gesture.translation.width > 0 && exceedsThreshold(gesture: gesture, geometryWidth: geometry.size.width) && currentIndex == 1 {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.translation.width = geometry.size.width
                                currentIndex = max(0, currentIndex - 1)
                            }
                        }
                    }  else {
                        withAnimation(.interactiveSpring()) {
                            if currentIndex == 0 {
                                self.translation.width = 0
                            } else {
                                self.translation.width = -geometry.size.width
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you're creating a custom Pager... Have you already tried converting a TabView into a PageTabView() or using the SwiftUIPager https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftUIPager ?

Comment: I don't think the solution provided by SwiftUIPager is reliable enough. I wanted to have a custom one so that I can control the whole look and feel e.g. have a custom tab indicator and also I want to be able to place views of different types within the Pager.